# How to sort on two variables

Tags: r, ggplot2

This is how my data is structured :

```
numClickBool rate rates bookedOrClick
1   0   L   1   0
2   5   M   1   0
3   11  B   1   0
4   0   L   1   1
5   0   M   1   1
6   5   B   1   1
7   8   L   2   0
8   128 M   2   0
9   34  B   2   0
10  6   L   2   1
11  86  M   2   1
12  30  B   2   1
13  12  L   3   0
14  98  M   3   0
15  20  B   3   0
16  8   L   3   1
```

I would like to plot for each rates in a rate the `numClickBool` of booked and clicked (`book == 0` and `Click == 1`), which should look like this (there are 8 rate and 3 rates (L M B), and each have a number of click, and a number of book):

[image: objectif plot]

What I have managed to make is this:

```
library(reshape2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data = ratePlotData, aes(x=rates, y = numClickBool, fill = bookedOrClick)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

which gives this :

[image: R plot]

Answer (score 2):

Although it's not very clear what you want to achieve, I think you need a faceted solution:

```
ggplot(data = ratePlotData, aes(x=rates, y = numClickBool, fill = as.factor(bookedOrClick))) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  facet_wrap(~ rate)
```

which gives:
[image]